# Contacts/Friends list functionality in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, contacts

I am working on an iOS application that allows users to send their location to a handful of their friends. Where I'm having difficulty is the actual friends list functionality. All my research just results in getting your friends list from Facebook. This is a proprietary friends list within my app, similarly to Snapchat. I do not want to get friends through another party. Users are stored using Parse so it would be preferred to have my friends list logic using Parse. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So you want to retrieve users from the contacts app on the device? If so have a look at this: https://github.com/SocialbitGmbH/SwiftAddressBook

Comment: Not necessarily. I just want to have a proprietary friends list on my app. If you look at snapchat and go to your friends, it's your snapchat friends. Not your Facebook friends or Address Book friends (though the friends may overlap).

Answer (score 0):

So you want people using your app to be able to send friend requests and become friends?

I did this with a `Relation` column in Parse named "Friends", in the User class.

To send and receive requests, I made a class "FriendReqeust" with two `Pointer` columns, "fromUser" and "toUser", and a `String`, "status".

Display the friend request properly and add buttons for accept and decline. It's easy to create a new relation for the accepting user, and add that one in to his/hers Relation column, but to add it to the FriendRequestSender you need to use Cloud Code.

Example Code for accepting request (friend added to currentUser if Cloud Code succeeds):

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("addFriendToFriendsRelation", withParameters: ["friendRequest":friendRequestId]) {
            (response: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

                var friendsRelation = self.toUser!.relationForKey("friendRelations")
                friendsRelation.addObject(self.fromUser!)
                self.toUser!.saveInBackground()

            } else {
                println(error)
            }
        }
```

If you know how to translate Objective-C to Swift, I recommend the answer to this question.
https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/parsecom-swift-how-do-you-add-pfusercurrentuser-to-another-users-relations-using-cloud-code-the-master-key

Then you can query Friends from any user.